# Routing in MVC2. Attributes are not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

Good time! There was a problem displaying the route in the input URL browser. To the search page on the site. The search itself is working fine - the "key" is passed, the list of found displayed. Search method in the controller takes an argument of type string for which to search:

```
public ActionResult SearchAllByKey(string key)
        {
            //logic
            return View(<list_of_found>);
        }
```

In Global.asax prescribed route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                  "Search",
                  "Search/{key}", 
                  new { controller = "controller_name", action = "SearchAllByKey", key = UrlParameter.Optional } 
              );
```

Form which sends the value of Edit to method from View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAllByKey", "controller_name", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                           {%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
                        <input type="text" id="keyValue" name="key" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
                        <% } %>
```

When you click on "Go!". to a page of search results, but the URL (input line browser) shows:

```
http://localhost:PORT/Search
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:PORT/Search/SOME_KEY
```

How to make sure that was visible "key" in the URL-e? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're POSTing your data.

Change your FORM with `FormMethod.Get` and make sure your action only accepts get (it's the default, though)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchAllByKey(string key)
    {
        //logic
        return View(new List<string>());
    }
```

**UPDATE**:

To achieve what you want you have to configure your ruote before the default:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
          "Search",
          "{controller}/SearchAllByKey/{key}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "SearchAllByKey", key = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );

routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Your **FORM** should look like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{%>
    <% Html.ValidationSummary(true); %>
    <input type="text" id="key" name="key" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
<% } %>
```

and you have to change your **ActionResult** like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchAllByKey(string key)
{
    //logic
    return View(new List<string>());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection form)
{
    return RedirectToAction("SearchAllByKey",  new { key = form["key"] });
}
```

Basically, your **FORM** posts to the action `Search` which redirects to `SearchAllByKey`.

Comment: but should be: localhost:7127/Search/nature

Comment: Thank you! I answered the question, "Was this post useful to you?" - Yes! Is that correct?